# mouseclick gui to return row and column

Tags: python, tkinter

I need a GUI,when i click over the screen, it should return me the row and column.

I did a coding,which displays row and column,but i dont want to display it.Is there any other way than using label to return the row and column.

I need not want the label displaying,instead if i click the `Plane/Blank GUI` it must return the output in the shell

My coding:

```
import Tkinter
root = Tkinter.Tk()
def unshow_me(event):
    event.widget.grid_forget()

def handle_click(text):
    print text
    a=text
for r in range(3):
    for c in range(6):
        text = 'R=%s,C=%s'%(r,c)
        label = Tkinter.Label(root, text=text, borderwidth=1 )
        label.grid(row=r,column=c)
        label.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e, text=text:handle_click(text),unshow_me)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to find the pixel coordinates of where the user clicked on the screen, don't even bother making labels. Just bind the root's click event directly.

```
import Tkinter
root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
def clicked(event):
    print "The user clicked at coordinates", event.x, event.y
root.bind("<Button-1>", clicked)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks,but i needed it in rows and column as we position the grid in tkinter.Could u help with that!

Comment: Divide x by the width of a column, and divide y by the height of a row. Then you'll have the row and column numbers.

Comment: so should i divide it like event `x/500, event.y/500` but i get `0,0` as input even at the edge of screen..Please help!

Comment: I get as `0,0` even if i click anywhere on GUI.

Comment: If your row is 500 pixels tall, then a 500x500 window would contain only one row. So it makes sense that it always says you're in row 0.

Comment: So,what should i change in the values!

Comment: You should not be dividing by 500. As I said, divide by the width of a column, and the height of a row. (hint: if you have 5 columns in a window with width 500, then a single column has a width of 100)